# MPI try to gather data from different arrays in different processors

Tags: c++, mpi

Excuse me I am a noob in MPI.

I have an array of different length in each processor and I want to either redistribute the data among each processor in a certain pattern or to gather them together using some rules. Could I still do it parallel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI Receive/Gather Dynamic Vector Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080845/mpi-receive-gather-dynamic-vector-length)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPI Receive/Gather Dynamic Vector Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080845/mpi-receive-gather-dynamic-vector-length)